# Laravel Eloquent Join Three tables together

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

I have a table `actors` with CSV in one of the columns

```
id      | suburb                         | name
1       | Newport, Williamstown, Altona  | Stephen
2       | Seaholme, Footscary            | George
```

I have normalized the table into a different table `actors_suburb`

```
actor_id| suburb
1       | Newport
1       | Williamstown
1       | Altona
2       | Seaholme
2       | Footscary
```

I have a different table `suburbs_near`

```
 suburb   |  Council
 Newport  |  Hobson
 Footscary|  Hobson
```

I want to return all the actors in a council this is what I've tried

```
if (isset($input['council']) && $input['council'] != '')
        {

            $query = $query->join('actors_suburb', 'actors.id', '=', 'actors_suburb.actor_id')
                           ->join('suburb_near', 'actors_suburb.suburb', '=', 'suburb_near.suburb')
                           ->select(array('actors.*', 'actors_suburb.*', 'suburb_near.suburb' , 'suburb_near.council'))
                           ->where('council', 'like', '%'. $input['council'].'%')
                           ->orderBy('views', 'desc');
        }
```

But it is not returning any results when I put in ?council=Hobson, which should return some results.  Please help.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use Eloquent ORM methods instead of hardcoding those joins? I'd suggest real normalizing those tables, that is creating pivot table to link actors & suburbs and if one suburb can be linked with only one Council, then get rid of suburbs_near table, create councils table and add council_id in the suburbs table. At last, show whole query, otherwise it's just guessing..

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this is incorrect, I would try a comment but I've not got the reputation yet. I'm only just learning Eloquent, but ren't you missing a ->get() or ->paginate(10)?

```
->orderBy('views', 'desc')->get();
```